# Systemd unit not found on start but exists on status

Tags: service, systemctl

A service exists and succesfully found via status command

```
>sudo systemd status my-service
● my-service.service - My service description
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/my-service.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

however, just in next command:

```
>sudo systemctl start my-service
Failed to start my-service.service: Unit not found.
```

I have absolutely no idea where to look Nothing changed between commands, they give same result even if eexecuted together via bash-scripot or connected with `;`

Comment: Check for the file mentioned, `/usr/lib/systemd/system/my-service.service`. Is it there? If it is, read it, it's a script, find what it does and how.

Comment: yeah, thanks. The service, that is required was not present.. But why doesn't it write, WHICH service not found?